# Cant get offset of div

Tags: javascript, css

this is my getoffset js code to get div width and left

```
  var objRedPacketDivStyle = document.getElementById("styRedPacketAppear");
        var objOffset = objRedPacketDivStyle.offset();
        var intWidth = objOffset.offsetWidth;
        var objWidthStart = objOffset.offset.left;
        var objWidthEnd = objWidthStart + intWidth;
        alert(objWidthStart + objWidthEnd);
```

and here is my div and css

```
<div class="styRedPacketAppear" id="styRedPacketAppear"></div>

#styRedPacketAppear {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 98;
pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: where the JS code is placed?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Please be more specific, are there errors in the console or what is happening that you did not intend to happen?

Comment: See in F12-> console the errors

Comment: I think `.offset()` belong to Jquey not javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't working as `.offset()` is a [jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/) method. Since you don't have jquery you need to use vanilla javascript to achieve this.

You can use:

- `element.offsetWidth`: *"returns the layout width of an element as an integer."* - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)
- `element.offsetLeft`: *"returns the number of pixels that the upper left corner of the current element is offset to the left within the HTMLElement.offsetParent node."* - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft)

Using these two properties will resolve your issue:

```js
var objRedPacketDivStyle = document.getElementById("styRedPacketAppear");
// Remove this: var objOffset = objRedPacketDivStyle.position.offset();
var intWidth = objRedPacketDivStyle.offsetWidth;
var objWidthStart = objRedPacketDivStyle.offsetLeft;
var objWidthEnd = objWidthStart + intWidth;
alert(objWidthStart + objWidthEnd);
```

```css
#styRedPacketAppear {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 98;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="styRedPacketAppear" id="styRedPacketAppear"></div>
```

Comment: nice... That's what I just came to post .. (LOL)

Comment: @ChauChun no worries! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The offsetTop property returns the top position (in pixels) relative to the top of the offsetParent element.
The returned value includes:
-the top position, and margin of the element
-the top padding, scrollbar and border of the offsetParent element.

```html
#test {
  top: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  border: 5px solid black
}

var testDiv = document.getElementById("test");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = testDiv.offsetTop;

Result-offsetTop is: 110
```